# Request: References and/or guidelines to assess the compactness of $D_{\infty h}$

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, compactness, locally-compact-groups

Can the community suggest "good" references for learning how to assess the compactness or lack of thereof in this particular case? Otherwise, I may need guidelines to approach/solve the problem at hand.

Comment: What is $D_{\infty h}$? Is it all reflections and rotations of the unit circle?

Comment: It also includes a mirror in the plane containing the circle. There are many notations for it, I am using the so called Schoenflies notation. Geometrical interpretations can be found from one of the types of Frieze groups or considering the symmetries of a barrel (a cylindrical vessel thicker at the middle), where the plane of the mirror is the one containing the larger circle at the middle of the length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are dealing with a point group consisting of rotations and reflections, that is, a subgroup of the orthogonal group $O(3)$. The orthogonal group is a closed and bounded subset of the set of square matrices, and thus by the Heine-Borel theorem is compact. It follows that any closed (i.e. contains all its limit points) subgroup of $O(3)$ is also compact (closed subsets of compact sets are compact; this may be found in a Real Analysis text, such as that of Rudin).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'll look at Rudin (I suppose it is not the so called "little Rudin" from undergraduate analysis) in order to justify compactness via Heine-Borel theorem.

Comment: Now I understand how you are leveraging on Heine-Borel theorem. What I need to know now is how to assess that $D_{\infty h}$ contain exactly all the limit points of the orthogonal group, i.e. asses the closure of $D_{\infty h}$. This not as easy as in  $D_n$, but I'm enjoying the reading.

Comment: This can be argued in several ways. One way is to argue that $D_{\infty h}$ is (I believe, based on your description) the set of rotations which take a plane $P$ into itself, i.e. $gP \subseteq P$ for $g \in O(3)$. The set $\{g \in O(3) \mid gP \subseteq P\}$ can be checked to be closed. Another way is to try to write down equations which define $D_{\infty h}$, and then using continuity of expressions involved in the equations.

Comment: Yesterday I followed the second approach and solved the problem (I agree that the first approach is far more elegant, but I'll need the equations latter). I am marking your answer as correct as clearly provided the directions I was looking for. Thanks!